# How to pass optional values generated from dynamic Text Boxes to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've a Form which dynamically populates textboxes depending on user requirements. I would like to fetch the values of those textboxes and pass it to Database.

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1v2E.png)

I'm using Entity Framework where in I've created a Model to accept values from View.

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<string> Question { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Intent { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Answer { get; set; }
```

In this case my model is static. How will the Database map the values to columns from List<> ?

Ps : I'm using Code first approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind list of object to textboxs or any other control with name conventions by looping through the list and populating inputs with required name for example:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
    {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.Questions[i]) 
    }
```

or by this way

```
for(int i=0;i<Model.Questions.Count;i++)
{
<input type='text' name="Questions[@i]" />
}
```

you can find more at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/introduction-to-model-binding-in-Asp-Net-mvc/